# Creating Multiple Search Criteria in React

Tags: reactjs, search, filter

I am not an expert and know that I am doing something wrong here, but at my wits end. I am trying to create multiple filters in React, using UseState, and useEffect.

-I want to have one search input that filters the search in title AND description - I am wondering why it is only looking through the description?

-adding data.filter for price is also a huge problem. It does not show any products until you type the minPrice in the input.

******************************Grid Component

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { BsFillGridFill } from 'react-icons/bs';
import { FaThList } from 'react-icons/fa';
import SingleList from '../products/SingleList';
import Card from '../products/Card';
import SideFilter from './SideFilter';

const GridList = (props) => {
    //select between grid or list
    const [choice, setChoice] = useState(true);
    // search input
    const [search, setSearch] = useState('');
    // minPrice
    const [minPrice, setMinPrice] = useState('');
    // max price
    const [maxPrice, setMaxPrice] = useState('');
    // filter the products coming through
    const [filteredData, setFilteredData] = useState([]);
    // filters

    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    // to show loading boyeeeeee
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        setLoading(true);
        const fetchData = async () => {
            const result = await axios.get('https://fakestoreapi.com/products');
            setData(result.data);
            setLoading(false);
        };

        fetchData();
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        let filteredSearch = () => {
            setFilteredData(
                data.filter((data) => {
                    return (data.title && data.description)
                        .toLowerCase()
                        .toLowerCase()
                        .includes(search.toLowerCase()) && data.price >= minPrice;
                })
            );
        };

        filteredSearch();
    }, [search, minPrice, maxPrice, data]);

    const onSearchChange = (e) => setSearch(e.target.value);
    const onMinPriceChange = (e) => setMinPrice(e.target.value);

    return (
        <div className='choice-div'>
            <SideFilter
                onSearchChange={onSearchChange}
                onMinPriceChange={onMinPriceChange}
            />
            <div className='grid-list-choice'>
                <div className='box-choice' onClick={() => setChoice(true)}>
                    <BsFillGridFill />
                </div>
                <div className='box-choice' onClick={() => setChoice(false)}>
                    <FaThList />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div className='grid-or-list'>
                {loading && <p>Loading...</p>}
                <div className={`grid ${!choice ? 'grid-chosen' : ''}`}>
                    <div className='product-grid'>
                        {filteredData.map((d) => (
                            <Card
                                key={d.id}
                                productImage={d.image}
                                productPrice={d.price}
                                productTitle={d.title}
                            />
                        ))}
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div className={`list ${choice ? 'grid-chosen' : ''}`}>
                    <div className='productList'>
                        {filteredData.map((d) => (
                            <SingleList
                                key={d.id}
                                listImage={d.image}
                                listPrice={d.price}
                                listTitle={d.title}
                            />
                        ))}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default GridList;
```

************************* Filter Component

```
import React from 'react';

const SideFilter = (props) => {
    return (
        <div className='side-filter'>
            <input
                className='search-input'
                type='text'
                placeholder='Search'
                onChange={props.onSearchChange}
            />
            <input
                className='search-input'
                type='text'
                placeholder='Minimum Price'
                onChange={props.onMinPriceChange}
            />
        </div>
    );
};

export default SideFilter;
```

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong, but it looks like there is something wrong with your return statement in your filter callback.  It looks like you are calling .toLowerCase twice on (data.title && data.desc) and then checking if it includes the parameters you a searching for.  If we use the logical and operator on two elements inside of brackets, I think Javascript returns the last element.  So, in the case of (data.title && data.description) this will simply return data.description, upon which you then call .toLowerCase.  This would explain why you maybe getting results that only look through the description.  Try separating the search like so:

```
return data.title && data.description && data.title.includes(...) && data.description.includes(...) && data.price >= minPrice && data.price <= maxPrice;
```

Comment: Thank you, Ashish! It makes sense. In the case of the maxPrice filter, how would I trigger that only if the field is not blank? I noticed that when I include the maxPrice, or minPrice filter, it returns no products until I type something in the input.

Comment: I think you can just check to see if maxPrice is an empty string or not.  In the case that it is, we can simply return true, otherwise we can actually make a comparison.  So something like this: (maxPrice === "" ? true : data.price <= maxPrice). This should work since if you haven't typed something in for maxPrice, it defaults to "", and <= comparisons between any positive integer and "" will always be false.  So that might be why you aren't getting products when adding a maxPrice filter.

Answer (score 0):

For this, I usually combine all the search fields into a single string and apply the filter to that, ie:

```js
data.filter((data) => {
    if (
        `${data.title.toLowerCase()}${data.description.toLowerCase()}`
        .includes(search.toLowerCase()) 
        && data.price >= minPrice
    ) return true
    return false
})
```

if you want price to be able to be blank:

```js
data.filter((data) => {
    if (
        `${data.title.toLowerCase()}${data.description.toLowerCase()}`
        .includes(search.toLowerCase()) 
        && (minPrice 
            ? data.price >= minPrice
            : true)
    ) return true
    return false
})
```

Comment: Appreciate the response! The way you did it is exactly how I had to configure the code to make it work. Thank you